# Open souce OSCP Server

Tags: ocsp

I'm looking for an opensource, freeware OCSP (Online Certificate Status Protocol) for installing in a linux OS.
I'm having a hard time finding a good one. 
Can anyone give some insights about some good options?

Thanks,
Raul

Comment: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ocsp(1)#OCSP_SERVER_OPTIONS

Comment: Hi Pedro, Thanks for your help me. The openssl ocsp has a cluster option or a bridge? I've looking for it and didn't found it.